# Use catalyst and Ajax to refresh an SVG block

Tags: javascript, jquery, perl, svg, catalyst

I am building a web app in which I have a number of clickable maps, stored as static SVG files, that I would like to be able to swap dynamically based on a menu-click. So far, I have javascript code to call my Catalyst controller, and I would like it to return the contents of the SVG file in the response body. So far I can get the javascript to catch the menu clicks and call the controller, and in the controller I am able to get the name of the file out of my database. I am stuck at that step, though, and have been thus far unable to find out how to read the contents of that file in the controller and return it to the javascript controller. Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE:

The (Edited) code below works, but I'm not sure if this is the best way. I would definitely be open to suggestions on ways to improve my process. Thanks!

Javascript:

```
$(document).on("click",".map_select", function(e){
    $(document.getElementById("som_map")).load("[% c.uri_for('/maps/update_map/') %]" + this.title);
})
```

HTML

```
<svg id="som_map" class="mapmain" width="720px" height="430px">
</svg>
```

PERL

```
sub update_map :Path :Local :Args(1) {
    my ( $self, $c, $map_id ) = @_;

    my $fields = $c->model('DB::Map')->find($map_id);
    my $map_file = $fields->get_column('map_file');

    my $svg;
    my $path = "root/static/svg/$map_file";
    open my $fh, '<', $path;
    {
        local $/ = undef;
        $svg = <$fh>;
    }
    close $fh;
    $c->res->body($svg);
}
```

SVG files are stored in root/static/svg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a reason to do it, I would use your web server (Apache, nginx, ...) serve the file for you instead of handling the file I/O inside of your controller.

In your load function in javascript pass in a function that returns a URL for you:

```
$(document.getElementById("som_map")).load(getSVGUrl(this.title));
```

Then define that function to call Catalyst to get the appropriate URL for the given mapId:

```
function getUrl(mapId) {
  var returnUrl;
  jQuery.ajax({
     url:      "[% c.uri_for('/maps/update_map/') %]"
               + mapId,
     success:  function(result) {
                   if(result.isOk == false)
                       returnUrl = result.message;
               },
     async:    false,
     dataType: 'text/plain'
  }); 
  return returnUrl;
}
```

This function should call your application and just expect to get the URL back.  It should be fast enough that making it synchronous does not matter.

Finally, your Catalyst function should just return the URL to the document:

```
sub update_map :Path :Local :Args(1) {
    my ( $self, $c, $map_id ) = @_;

    my $fields = $c->model('DB::Map')->find($map_id);
    my $map_file = $fields->get_column('map_file');

    $c->res->body("<appropriate URL path to document>/$map_file");
}
```

This will get your application out of the document handling business, trim down your controller, and allow your web server to do what it does best - serve documents.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Having catalyst serve up the file was the part of my way I was most unsure about, both from efficiency and security standpoints. I've updated my code to use this method. Unfortunately, I'm not getting a valid URL (or anything, apparently) out of the call to JQuery.ajax. I can see from the log output that the controller is being hit, and can print the return URL to the log and see that it's okay. However, the map is not updating and console.log(returnUrl); placed after the call to JQuery.ajax comes up as "undefined." Can't figure out why!

Comment: So it turns out that the `success ...` block is not being run. Adding `error: function(result) { console.log("error"); }` prints to the console, however. Not sure why, since my logs show the controller sending the response with a 200 code. Very puzzled here!

Comment: Got it working! I've edited the code in the reply to reflect the changes I had to make.